# A swifty way to type the following if statemnt

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner and I was wondering if there's a nicer way to write the following code? 
It looks very messy with all the if statements. 
Any suggestions?

```
static func generateWord (_ data : GameDataManager) {
    let lang = L102Language.currentAppleLanguage()
    if lang != "en" {
        if game.wordsList.count == 0 {
            helper.hebrewWords()
        }
    }else{
       if game.wordsList.count == 0 {
            helper.englishWords()
        }
    }
    if game.floffWords.count < 2  {
        createArrayOfWords()
        if game.floffWords.isEmpty {
            print("Oops games over")
        } else {
            data.word = game.floffWords.randomElement()!
        }
    } else {
        data.word = game.floffWords.randomElement()!
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to check whether `floffWords` is empty after `game.floffWords = createArrayOfWords()`? Can `createArrayOfWords` create an empty array?

Comment: You could start by identing it better...

Comment: Yeah, createArrayOfWords can return an empty array once the user played all the games. is there any way around this ?

Comment: Please check your code indenting first...

Comment: what do you mean by code indenting?

Comment: It means the tab/spaces at start of the lines. Select your code in XCode, and Cmd+I to fix indentation and then copy/paste it here.

Comment: Oh nice one, in visual studio it would automatically do this whenever I save the project. I've updated the code above. Is there a way to make floffwords.randomElement not an optional value?

Comment: Start by making `lang` an `enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you if this will *do what you want*, but it's the same logic.

```swift
if game.wordsList.isEmpty {
  switch L102Language.currentAppleLanguage() {
  case "en":
    helper.englishWords()
  default:
    helper.hebrewWords()
  }
}

switch game.floffWords.count {
case ..<2:
  createArrayOfWords()

  if game.floffWords.isEmpty {
    print("Oops games over")
  } else {
    fallthrough
  }
default:
  data.word = game.floffWords.randomElement()!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the exclamation mark, change

```
data.word = game.floffWords.randomElement()!
```

to

```
if let randomWord = game.floffWords.randomElement() {
    data.word = randomWord
}
```

You could then DRY out the repetition into a method if desired. Even better, promote that method to be part of `game`.